# puntero tridimensional con memoria dinamica

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define FIL 13

#define COL 50

int main ()
{
    int quantita=2;
    char (*dato) [FIL][COL];
    dato = ( char (*) [FIL][COL] ) malloc (quantita * FIL * COL * sizeof (char) );
    return 0;
}
```

Esta *brujería* fue una asignación de memoria dinámica a un puntero a 2 grupos de 13 punteros que apuntan a un espacio de 50 elementos cada uno.
Funciona? Si.. como yo quiero? si y no.
Se puede usar un array de punteros para lo mismo? Si. Porque no lo usaste? Quería probar esto que no esta en las bibliografías.
Cual era mi idea inicial? Crear una matriz tridimensional de forma dinámica. Asique cree un puntero capaz de saltar `quantita*FIL*COL` bytes cada vez que se uso aritmética.
Como lo uso? Luego de que `malloc` me da la memoria como un puntero tridimensional normal.

Da error al compilar? No, uso GCC.

**Problema:**

El problema es que a la CADENA `dato[0][1]` le entra basura luego de escribirla. La única.
Que tipo de basura? pedazos de la salida en pantalla (aunque suene extraño).
Probé un compilador online, funciona bien. Aunque un poco lento en la carga de datos (no se si es por que es online, no estoy habituado a usarlos).
El resto de las cadenas funciona bien? Si, solo la segunda del primer grupo de arrays.
Ya mire las direcciones de memoria y lo interesante es que la primera me la hace mas corta (son saltos de 50 bytes (32 en hexa)). Pongo las 4 primeras, el resto son todas iguales. Los ceros que no estan escritos son ascii basura, no aparece porque no escribe nada. Pense que era la memoria quemada en esos bytes lo descarte porque siempre lo hace independiente la direccion de donde empiece. Lo extraño es que siempre anda mal la segunda cadena independientemente de la direccion y la primera es mas corta.

Foto de la memoria (puse todos los bytes a cero, menos los que no se escriben no se porque)

0x55eec570e2a0:

00000000000000000000000000000000

0x55eec570e2d2:

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

0x55eec570e304:

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

0x55eec570e336:

00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

(.... siguen mas direcciones... todo normal)

Acepto comentarios, sugerencias, experiencias.

Cordiales saludos.

Comment: No veo en el código que estés "llenando" la memoria, ¿te faltó agregar esta parte o estas suponiendo que  `malloc()`  inicializa la memoria reservada?

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio por responderme, no la puse porque no queria aburrir con tanto codigo. Para llenar de ceros hice tres for

for  (int i=0; i<quantita; i++)
   { for (int j=0; j<FIL; j++)
     { printf ("%p:\n", dato[i][j]);
      for (int k=0; k<COL; k++)
       { dato[i][j][k]='\0';
        printf ("%d", dato[i][j][k]);
       }
      printf ("\n");
     }
    printf ("\n");
   }

   printf ("\n");printf ("\n");

  getchar ();

De esta forma genere ese grafico, elemento por elemento. Te cuento que probe el programa con un array tridimensional sin malloc, funciona bien

Comment: El tema es que `malloc()` solo reserva el espacio, lo que hay adentro de ese espacio, nadie lo sabe. Puedes probar también con `calloc()` que reserva e inicializa.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta y pon el código ahí. No uses los comentarios para complementar la respuesta. Si obligas a que la gente tenga que leerse los comentarios para poder responder vas a perder respuestas